# Does this system have an analytical solution?

Tags: vector-analysis, nonlinear-system, integro-differential-equations

I am dealing with the system
$$\begin{cases}y'(x)=y(x)(1-z(x))\\ z'(x)=y(x)-z(x)\end{cases}$$

Maybe there is an analytical solution?

I write $e^x(z'+z)=e^xy$, so
$$z=e^{-x}\int_0^x e^t y(t) dt,$$
what leads to
$$y'(x)=y(x)\left(1-e^{-x}\int_0^x e^t y(t) dt\right),$$
or
$$y'(x)=y(x)\left(1-\int_0^x e^{-(x-t)} y(t) dt\right),$$

Some help?

Some clue about the maximum and minimum points?

========

EDIT
$$y=z′+z
\\ y′=z′′+z′
\\ z′′+z′=(z′+z)(1−z)=z′−zz′+z−z^2
\\ z′′=−zz′−z^2+z.$$

Comment: $(y,z)=(0,0),(1,1)$ are two solutions.

Comment: $y=z'+z$, $y'=z''+z'$, $z''+z'=(z'+z)(1-z)=z'-zz'+z-z^2$, $z''=-zz'-z^2+z$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson yes, thank you, I tried this as you, any ideia?

Comment: It's usually best to include everything you know about a problem in your post of the question, so that no one wastes their time and yours in telling you things you already know. Anyway, we've reduced it to a nonlinear second-order differential equation for a single function. In general, there's no analytic solution for such things, but sometimes you get lucky. I'd suggest consulting an intro differential equations textbook to see whether anything like this one is discussed.

Comment: Thank you @GerryMyerson and sorry, I was more interested in $y$, so I did not think much about $z$, really sorry, I'll edit it

Comment: Well, you can eliminate $z$ instead, to get an equation for $y$, probably just as difficult.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I've edited

Comment: Eliminating $z$ instead, I get $yy''-(y')^2+yy'+y^3-y^2=0$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Interesting. I think really that is no analytical form.

Comment: Another solution is $(y,z)=(0,Ce^{-x})$.

Comment: FWIW, the equation for $z$ is autonomous and can be made first-order by a substitution $z'(x)=u(z)$. I get $uu'+zu+z^2-z=0$, which Wolfram identifies as an instance of Chini's equation.

Comment: @CW279 thank you, but why $uu'$ instead of $u'$ in the first term?

Comment: @CW279 if it is $u'$ instead of $uu'$ , the Wolfram has solution https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=u%27%2Bz*u%2Bz%5E2-z%3D0. Then, substituting $z'=u$, Wolfram says https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=z%27+%3D+c_1+e%5E%28-z%5E2%2F2%29+%2B+sqrt%28%CF%80%2F2%29+e%5E%28-z%5E2%2F2%29+erfi%28z%2Fsqrt%282%29%29+-+z+%2B+1

Comment: Unfortunately it has to be $uu'$. This is because 

$$
z''=\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{du}{dz}\,\frac{dz}{dx}=uu'
$$

Comment: Oh, yes, the chain rule